# Excel - How to change code to Workbook and not worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set KeyCells = Range("C9")
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        isect.Value = isect.Value - 40
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

what I want to do is make it universal, ie, work for all sheets not just one. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the code to the `ThisWorkbook` page

[image: vba]

and change the event to the `Workbook_SheetChange` event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set KeyCells = Range("C9")
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        isect.Value = isect.Value - 40
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```